# Parsing logs with logstash

Tags: logstash

I have my logs in this form :

```
 TFMLOG252252   1454964680185   2016-02-09 02:21:20.185 204 -   -   -   -   DEV gcfo    dev dev 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  a70d72f-1a-152c2a725f9000   INFO    INFO    -   -   -   -   applog.cls=com.walmart.ecommerce.getcustomerfulfillmentorder.cache.impl.GetCustomerFulfillOrderCacheManager,applog.mthd=getFulfillmentSystem,applog.line=40,applog.msg=Entered getfulfillmentSystem
TFMLOG252252    1454964690141   2016-02-09 02:21:30.141 204 -   -   -   -   DEV gcfo    dev dev 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  a70d72f-1a-152c2a74cdd000   INFO    INFO    -   -   -   -   applog.cls=com.walmart.ecommerce.getcustomerfulfillmentorder.camel.AuditEventNotifier,applog.mthd=notify,applog.line=26,applog.msg=Audit String: Endpoint//=Endpoint[http://dummyhost]//,TransId//=null//,Order Number//=201601290102//,NodeId//=5509//,CountryCode//=US//,FirstName//=null//,LastName//=PUTTESTING//,OrderType//=PUT//,MaxOrderCount//=32//,ResponseTime//=2131
TFMLOG252252    1454964900004   2016-02-09 02:25:00.004 204 -   -   -   -   DEV gcfo    dev dev 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  a70d72f-e-152c2aa80a4005    HB  LOG -   TH  COUNTS  -   sampling.rate=1024,quota.limit=10485760,quota.msg.dropped=0,sampling.msg.dropped=0,sampling.msg.received=7
TFMLOG252252    1454964688008   2016-02-09 02:21:28.008 204 -   -   -   -   DEV gcfo    dev dev 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT  a70d72f-1a-152c2a74488000   INFO    INFO    -   -   -   -   applog.msg=TransID//=213564 ENTERED IN FUNC FUL
```

Now I want to parse only logs of type 2 and type 4. How do I do that?

I had written this filter as of now :

```
   filter{

        grok{
            match => { "message" => "%{WORD:loggingid}\s*%{NUMBER:epoch}\s*%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s*%{NUMBER:system}\s*-\s*-\s*-\s*-\s*%{WORD:env}\s*%{WORD:appid}\s*%{WORD:dc}\s*%{WORD:envid}\s*%{NOTSPACE:appversion}\s*%{NOTSPACE:msgid}\s*%{WORD:msgtype}\s*%{WORD:msgsubtype}\s*-\s*-\s*-\s*-\s*%{GREEDYDATA:actuallog}"}
        }
}
```

This filter is able to parse Type 1,2 and 4 but fails on parsing type 3. I tried using %{WORD} for - but failed.

My logic was this : I thought I will write the actual log into field actual_log , then see if actual_log contains "TransId" or "TransID" else use drop filter to drop that log. In case the event is not dropped, I will use kv filter to get the key value pairs from the actual_log and remove the other unnecessary fields (Example : loggingid,epoch etc.) and then put it into elastic search .

Now I have few questions:

```
1) How to parse the "-" ? 
2) Is my logic correct?
```

One workaround , I was thinking of is that I can check if I get grokparsefailure, I will not put it in elastic search so I can drop it in between itself. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

As you should be aware, your pattern doesn't work on line three because you're expecting 4 hypens and that's not what's found in your input.

If these six values:

```
INFO    INFO    -   -   -   -
```

are the same fields as these values:

```
HB  LOG -   TH  COUNTS  -
```

then put them all into their own fields, regardless of whether the field contains "-" or something like "COUNTS".  As you discovered, %{WORD} does not match a hyphen, so you'd need to use something like %{NOTSPACE}.

If line 3 is really a different format, then consider pulling all the common stuff off the front (perhaps up to "msgsubtype") in one grok stanza, and then having another grok stanza with two patterns to deal with the more specific stuff.

I don't like to use grokparsefailure as anything but a trigger that input didn't match my pattern.  If you overload it with other functionality, you lose the basic feature.

Also note that %{SPACE} will handle "\s*" and is typically easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Alain. But can I put kv filter only in actuallog field? If yes, how?

Comment: kv{} takes a "source" value where you can specify the field with the data.

Comment: In the 4th type of log, Is there anyway by which I can the transid as the key? I included 
  kv{
   source => "actuallog"
   field_split => ",="
  }
in my filter and this gives correct results for logs of type 2 but doesn't work for log 4

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the @Alain answer.

You can use this grok for your need and use `kv` filter on `actuallog`:

```
%{WORD:loggingid}\s*%{NUMBER:epoch}\s*%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s*%{NUMBER:system}\s*-\s*-\s*-\s*-\s*%{WORD:env}\s*%{WORD:appid}\s*%{WORD:dc}\s*%{WORD:envid}\s*%{NOTSPACE:appversion}\s*%{NOTSPACE:msgid}\s*%{WORD:msgtype}\s*%{WORD:msgsubtype}\s*%{NOTSPACE}\s*%{NOTSPACE}\s*%{NOTSPACE}\s*%{NOTSPACE}\s*%{GREEDYDATA:actuallog}
```